# Getting Sweave code chunks inside some framed box?

Tags: r, latex, tex, sweave

I would like to make an R code chunk (in Sweave) printed inside a framed box in the resulting pdf.

Is there an easy solution for doing that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is that yes, there is an easy way.  Just add the following lines, or something like them to the preamble of your Sweave document:

```
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Sinput}{Verbatim} {xleftmargin=2em,
                                              frame=single}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Soutput}{Verbatim}{xleftmargin=2em,
                                              frame=single}
```

---

This works because the appearance of code (and output) chunks is controlled by the definition of the `Sinput` and `Soutput` environments. These are both `Verbatim` environments as provided by the LaTeX package `fancyvrb`. ([Click here](http://ftp.cvut.cz/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.pdf) for a 73 page pdf describing the numerous options that `fancyvrb` provides).

A quick look in the file `Sweave.sty` reveals the default definition of those two environments:

```
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Sinput}{Verbatim}{fontshape=sl}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Soutput}{Verbatim}{}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Scode}{Verbatim}{fontshape=sl}
```

To change those definitions, just add `\DefineVerbatimEnvironment` statements of your own devising either: (a) at the end of the `Sweave.sty` file; or (b) at the start of your `*.Snw` document.

---

Finally, here's an example to show what this looks like in practice:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{Sweave}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Sinput}{Verbatim} {xleftmargin=2em,
                                              frame=single}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Soutput}{Verbatim}{xleftmargin=2em,
                                              frame=single}
\title{Sweave with boxes}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

<<echo=FALSE>>=
options(width=60)
@

Here is an example of a code chunk followed by an output chunk,
both enclosed in boxes.

<<>>=
print(rnorm(99))
@

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Josh, I just made a followup question to this one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907613/getting-sweave-code-chunks-to-stay-inside-page-margins
I'd be happy for any comments.  Thanks again!

Comment: Nice answer. If I may ask, how about making the whole chunk fit into the frame?

Comment: @DominicComtois -- Good question. From the way those environments are defined (as separate `Sinput`, `Soutput`, and `Scode`, it doesn't seem like that'd be easy at all. Hacking Sweave was always a **huge** pain, which is why Yihui made **knitr**, and now that I've used that for a couple of years, I can't imagine ever going back!

Comment: Yeah I tried to apply the frame setting to the whole Schunk but it doesn't give the expected result at all. Knitr comes back again and again in discussions, I will probably give it a shot.

Comment: @DominicComtois -- Good to  hear. I was a bit slow to adopt **knitr** but haven't ever regretted it. [Here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030898/knitr-how-to-align-code-and-plot-side-by-side/23396783#23396783) of something fairly sophisticated that I just put together with **knitr** and which would have been flat out impossible using **Sweave**.

Answer (score 2):

[`knitr`](http://yihui.name/knitr/), a successor of `Sweave`, by default outputs all echoed R code in boxes, and also formats it to the margins. Other nice features include syntax coloring and PGF integration.

`Sweave` code of average complexity needs only minor if any adaptions to run with `knitr`.