# Getting Sweave code chunks to stay inside page margins?

Tags: r, latex, tex, sweave

Sometimes I get to make an R code chunk (in Sweave) which is longer then the margins of the page.  Is there a way to force it to "go to the next line" once that happens?

Here is a simple example of that happening:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{Sweave}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Sinput}{Verbatim} {xleftmargin=2em,
                                              frame=single}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Soutput}{Verbatim}{xleftmargin=2em,
                                              frame=single}
\title{Sweave with boxes}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

<<echo=FALSE>>=
options(width=60)
@

Here is an example of a code chunk followed by an output chunk,
both enclosed in boxes.

<<>>=
print(rnorm(99))
@


<<>>=
print("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa")
@


\end{document}
```

Comment: I think that `knitr` should solve that... I'm not absolutely sure, but try it out. It's on CRAN now.

Comment: Hi alexa - I had a feeling it might, and I am hoping to avoid it at this point...

Comment: In similar cases, I use package listings and \lstset{breaklines=true}

Comment: Hi Dieter - I just tried it but with no success.

Comment: @TalGalili: Hi, just being curious: Is this a sweave problem or rather a problem of the verbatim environment of LaTeX? In this case one might try solving this in latex (http://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Seb - good idea, I just posted it...

Comment: I believe this is more a LaTeX problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907613/getting-sweave-code-chunks-to-stay-inside-page-margins

Comment: Here's the link to Tal's tex.stackexchange post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41471/getting-sweave-code-chunks-to-stay-inside-page-margins

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a difficult and extreme case, because you do not have spaces among those `a`'s, so LaTeX may not be able to wrap the words. If you do have spaces, `knitr` will be able to produce the output with the long lines wrapped with `tidy=TRUE, highlight=TRUE` (so will Sweave, I think, if you set `keep.source=FALSE`).