# How to set knitr chunk output width on a per chunk basis?

Tags: r, knitr

### My question(s):

Does **knitr** have an option that allows one to set R's `width` option on a per chunk basis?

If not, is there a good reason (i.e. one rooted in some fundamental limitation of the **knitr** model) that it does not?

### What I've tried:

To show what I'm wishing for, here is a hand-rolled hook function that does **basically** what I want. (I don't really like it though, (a) because it is ugly, relying on assignment of the variable `.width` into the global environment, and (b) because it's not available "out of the box" as a supplied option like `fig.width`, `out.width`, et al.)

```
\documentclass[preview=true,width=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
options(width=60)

knit_hooks$set(width = function(before, options, envir) {
if(before) {
    .width <<- options(width=options$width) ## Set width and save 'old' value
} else {
    options(.width)}                        ## Restore width's 'old' value
})

@

First chunk uses default width
<<A>>=
c("aaaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc", "ddddd", "eeeee", "fffff", "ggggg", "hhhhh")
@

Second chunk uses narrower supplied width, but then resets width to
pre-existing value \dots
<<B, width=20>>=
c("aaaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc", "ddddd", "eeeee", "fffff", "ggggg", "hhhhh")
@

\noindent \dots as shown by results of the third chunk
<<C>>=
c("aaaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc", "ddddd", "eeeee", "fffff", "ggggg", "hhhhh")
@

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't this per-chunk width? You set the default to 60, which is in effect for any chunk that doesn't explicitly change it. Are you trying to permanently change the default value?

Comment: @Tyler -- So my questions are: (1) is this functionality already available in knitr, and (2) if not, is there some enlightening reason why it isn't? I'd also be interested in (3) knowing how my hook function might be tweaked so that it doesn't require that ugly assignment of `.width` into the global environment. I've tried but can't figure out a workaround that avoids that. Those are the reasons I've asked the question, despite having cobbled together a solution that basically works...

Comment: (The bigger picture is that I'm working on **knitr** code that'll typeset code and figures side by side. Doing that would be a bit simpler if there were an `output.width` option that I could pass into chunks that were to produce that sort of side-by-side output.)

Comment: I follow now. I was thinking you were trying to set the width in the latex contex, but you're working with *R*'s width for output.

Comment: I don't know of something in knitr that does this already, but you can remedy your issue #a (global var) using `local`, replacing your set call with something like `knit_hooks$set(width=local({ .width <- 0 ; function(before, options, envir) { if (before) .width <<- options(width=options$width) else options(.width) } ; }))`.

Comment: @r2evans -- Interesting thought, but have you actually made that work? `knit_hooks$set()` expects to be passed function definitions taking three arguments (`before`, `options`, and `envir`), which isn't what you're proposing handing in to it...

Comment: I tested it before posting it. `local()` evaluates the R expression(s) in a new environment; after `.width` is defined, the last line of the block is a function definition which is returned, just as in your code. The difference? The scope of the (internally unnamed) function first checks its own env, then the parent env, which happens to be unique, created by `local()`, and not the overall global environment (though it would search there next if we didn't defined `.width`). It's still not beautiful, but you shouldn't have global var collisions.

Comment: @r2evans -- Very nice! Would you mind posting that as an answer? It could very well end up being the best solution we've got.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though not a solution to the overall question, your first complaint with your code is that it gums up the global environment with your `.width` variable. This can be resolved using `local()` as a **closure** mechanism, encapsulating your variable so that you get no collisions in global var space.

So, if you replace your `knit_hooks$set` call with:

```
knit_hooks$set(width=local({
    .width <- 0
    function(before, options, envir) {
        if (before) .width <<- options(width=options$width)
        else options(.width)
    }
}))
```

it produces the same results without the problem of forcing `.width` into the global environment. The rest of your code above works as before with identical output.

More can be read at `help(local)`, in [Advanced R Programming](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html) (Hadley Wickham), and there are several examples of it in the wild, such as @JeroenOoms' [OpenCPU](https://github.com/jeroenooms/opencpu).

Comment: Thanks. Very clever. I guess it would also be just as simple to construct a more general `R.opts` hook function, which takes an arbitrary list of global options (e.g. `list(width=60, warn=1, scipen=10)` to be set just for the current chunk.

Comment: Use this instead: `knit_hooks$set(r.opts=local({ ropts <- NA ; function(before, options, envir) { if (before) ropts <<- options(options$r.opts) else options(ropts) ; } }))`, and replace `<<B, width=20>>=` with `<<B, r.opts=list(width=20)>>=`.

Comment: This is a very handy solution.  However, I'd suggest to call the chunk option `output.width`, so it does not get confused with other `*.width` options.

Comment: @user101089: you're right, calling it `width` is certainly problematic but was merely demonstrative; I think `r.width` or `console.width` would possibly be clearer, since `output.width` in my mind might describe the rendered output of the knit document. I think a slightly better solution is in my previous comment which enables adjusting arbitrary R options. (@Yihui may argue that you can always just do `options(width=20)` directly in the chunk. We'll see.)

Comment: @r2evans -- (1) Using `r.opts` (maybe better named `r.global.opts`) seems like it removes any ambiguity about which width is being set, another point in its favor. (2) The downside of setting `options(width=20)` directly in the chunk (or in the chunk header) is that it resets the value for subsequent chunks as well. And finding a way to avoid that was pretty much the point of my question!

Comment: @Yihui -- In case you see this, does r2evans' look pretty optimal to you as well? Seems perfect behavior-wise, and so also optimal unless there's an even simpler way to do this...

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, I suggested it on [github](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/764) and he's thinking about it.

Comment: Good on you, thanks. I agree it'd make a great addition to **knitr**.

Comment: The new chunk option `R.options` is in the development version of knitr now.

Comment: The accepted answer above didn't work for me, but I'm happy to see the more general solution with `R.options` now supported in knitr 1.6. In a recent RStudio, this even appears as a suggested chunk option when you type in <<>>=. Great!

Answer (score 0):

This also answers my question. I am using Beamer and `knitr` to make overheads, and sometimes I make the output smaller (eg. to get an analysis of variance table in one piece without wrapping). For example, I have a default width of 50, but I can now do

```
{\small 
<<width=55>>=
  summary(my.aov)
@
}
```

and I get the P-values on the *same* lines as the sums of squares, yet the width is still 50 for subsequent chunks.